# How to Architect a scalable solution for User preference that triggers actions in an application based on state changes of domain model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, oop, refactoring

In my Rails app, I want to be able to listen for s**tate changes or callback triggers on the various Active Record model that exists**. I have opted out to use the Observer pattern by using [Rails Observer.](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers) So I can do this

```
class Product < ActiveRecord; end 

class ProductObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(product) 
     #do something here
  end

  def after_destroy(product)
    #do something here 
  end 
end
```

This is awesome. However, each retailer in the application can enable one or more settings. An example below

Assuming we have retailer A, B, C and D

**When a new product is created**,

*Retailer A has the following settings configured*:

- send me an email
- send all my customers newsletter
- send my previous sales report

*Retailer B has the following settings configured*

- send me an email

*Retailer C has the following settings configured*

- inform my customers about the new products

*Retailer D may decide they don't want anything to happen*

***Note***, these settings are all configurable from a UI.

Also, there would be various settings that can be configured on different callback triggers or model state change for the various ActiveRecord model in my application.

How do I model this problem so that it scales, testable and without coupling?

Here is a few solution I have come up with, but a colleague suggest they would prefer not to have verbs in their class name, but that is the most optimal solution I see for now.

```
class ProductObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(product)
    retailer = product.retailer 
    #find user settings from db 
    # fetch all methods they want to be triggered 
    # use meta programming to tirgger that method 

    retailer.observable_event_settings.actions.each do|action| 
      klass = "ProductCreate::#{action.camelize}".constantize
      klass.notify(product)
    end 
  end
end


module ObservableEvent 
  module ProductCreate 
    class SendNewsLetter
      def self.notify(observable)
      end 
    end 

    class OfferDiscount
      def self.notify(observable)
      end 
    end 
  end 
end 

#ObservableEvents 
[
  {
    id: 1, 
    model: 'product'
    event: 'create', 
    actions: [:send_news_letter, :offer_discount]
  },
  {
    id: 2, 
    model: 'product', 
    event: 'destroy'
    actions: [:set_product_not_visible, :set_quantity_to_zero]
  }
]

#ObservableEventSettings
[
  {
    retailer_id: 1, 
    observable_event_id: 1,
    actions: [:send_news_letter] 
  },

  {
    retailer_id: 2, 
    observable_event_id: 1, 
    actions: [:send_news_letter, :offer_discount]
  }
]
```

This is the best I have been able to come up with so far. How would you go around this? Any help is most appreciated.